# Delete a record from a database after a certain amount of time has passed

Tags: database, vb.net, visual-studio, ms-access

I'm asking for help again for another school project. So, the plan is to insert a record into a "Deleted Records" database and delete that from that database after a specific number of time has passed. For example, I inserted a record into that database and I want it deleted from the same database "exactly three years later". The current template in my head is:

```
Insert the record into the database along with the date it was inserted (Date.Today.ToShortDateString).
If row.Cells(8).Value (the date it was inserted) reached exactly 3 years old Then
Delete it from the database.
End If
```

I know how to insert and delete into and from a database. I just don't know what's the code when the date it was inserted reaches 3 years old.

Comment: You can't do that with just the database alone. You would need to run some sort of regular task that will look for records older than a particular period and delete them.

Comment: Hi @Alex as John has said. You would need a separate program or job that will check the deleted records periodically.

Answer (score 2):

> I just don't know what's the code when the date it was inserted
> reaches 3 years old.

Using the [DateAdd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dateadd-function) function, add 3 years to the date the record was inserted and compare it to today's date.

```
DateAdd("yyyy", 3, [DateInsertedFieldName]) >= Date()
```

You can put the above condition on the `WHERE` clause of your delete query.

Comment: I haven't tried this yet but do you know if it's possible with minutes too? I want to check if it really works, like instead of 3 years, I'll try it for 5 minutes first.

Comment: Yes you can. Instead of years `yyyy` in the DateAdd function, add minutes `n` and change `>= Date()` to `>=Now()` since date does not hold time. The same applies for the database field - you need to store the date-time, not just the date (as in your example).

Comment: Thank you very much! I will click the check mark once I've tried it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a column of Date in **Deleted Records**, and use **Current Date** to automatically record the date when each piece of data was added.

Write a method for your program to delete data older than three years, and call it automatically under certain circumstances.